# Pandas concat dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, concatenation

I have an existing dataframe and I'm trying to concatenate a dictionary where the length of the dictionary is different from the dataframe

```
         A        B        C
0  0.46324  0.32425  0.42194
1  0.10596  0.35910  0.21004
2  0.69209  0.12951  0.50186
3  0.04901  0.31203  0.11035
4  0.43104  0.62413  0.20567
5  0.43412  0.13720  0.11052
6  0.14512  0.10532  0.05310
```

and

```py
test = {"One": [0.23413, 0.19235, 0.51221], "Two": [0.01293, 0.12235, 0.63291]}
```

I'm trying to add `test` to `df`, while changing the keys to `"D"` and `"C"` and I've had a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html and
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html which indicates that I should be able to concatenate the dictionary to the dataframe

I've tried:

```py
pd.concat([df, test], axis=1, ignore_index=True, keys=["D", "E"])
pd.concat([df, test], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

but I'm not having any luck, the result I'm trying to achieve is

```
         A        B        C        D        E
0  0.46324  0.32425  0.42194  0.23413  0.01293  
1  0.10596  0.35910  0.21004  0.19235  0.12235
2  0.69209  0.12951  0.50186  0.51221  0.63291
3  0.04901  0.31203  0.11035      NaN      NaN
4  0.43104  0.62413  0.20567      NaN      NaN 
5  0.43412  0.13720  0.11052      NaN      NaN
6  0.14512  0.10532  0.05310      NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way you can do that is with:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(test).rename(columns={'One':'D','Two':'E'}))

          A       B       C       D       E
0   0.46324 0.32425 0.42194 0.23413 0.01293
1   0.10596 0.35910 0.21004 0.19235 0.12235
2   0.69209 0.12951 0.50186 0.51221 0.63291
3   0.04901 0.31203 0.11035     NaN     NaN
4   0.43104 0.62413 0.20567     NaN     NaN
5   0.43412 0.13720 0.11052     NaN     NaN
6   0.14512 0.10532 0.05310     NaN     NaN
```

because as @Alexander mentioned correctly the number of rows being concatenated should match. Otherwise, as in your case, missing rows will be filled with `NaN`

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you want to add them as rows:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(test.values(), columns=df.columns)], ignore_index=True)
         A        B        C
0  0.46324  0.32425  0.42194
1  0.10596  0.35910  0.21004
2  0.69209  0.12951  0.50186
3  0.04901  0.31203  0.11035
4  0.43104  0.62413  0.20567
5  0.43412  0.13720  0.11052
6  0.14512  0.10532  0.05310
7  0.01293  0.12235  0.63291
8  0.23413  0.19235  0.51221
```

If added as new columns:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(test.values()).T], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
df_new.columns = \
    df.columns.tolist() + [{'One': 'D', 'Two': 'E'}.get(k) for k in test.keys()]

>>> df_new
         A        B        C        E        D
0  0.46324  0.32425  0.42194  0.01293  0.23413
1  0.10596  0.35910  0.21004  0.12235  0.19235
2  0.69209  0.12951  0.50186  0.63291  0.51221
3  0.04901  0.31203  0.11035      NaN      NaN
4  0.43104  0.62413  0.20567      NaN      NaN
5  0.43412  0.13720  0.11052      NaN      NaN
6  0.14512  0.10532  0.05310      NaN      NaN
```

Order is not guaranteed in dictionaries (e.g. `test`), so the new column names actually need to be mapped to the keys.

Answer (score 1):

To add a dictionary as **new columns**, another method is to convert it into a dataframe and simply assign.

```py
df[['D', 'E']] = pd.DataFrame(test)
```

[image: res1]

To add a dictionary as **new rows**, another method is to convert the dict into a dataframe using `from_dict` method and concatenate.

```py
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test, orient='index', columns=df.columns)], ignore_index=True)
```

[image: res2]