# Python dataframe append row with default value

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to append a row to a DataFrame in which the entire row should take on a default value. I see posts on adding a column with default values, but how do I append a row with default values?

Comment: apparently related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366036/pandas-concat-dictionary-to-dataframe

Answer (score 2):

When you say append I think you mean add a new row to the bottom of a dataframe with a default value like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({0: {0: 'March', 1: 2019, 2: 'A'},
 1: {0: 'April', 1: 2019, 2: 'E'},
 2: {0: 'May', 1: 2019, 2: 'F'}})

# where 1 is the default value
df.loc[3,:] = 1
```

Yeilds:

```
    0       1       2
0   March   April   May
1   2019    2019    2019
2   A       E       F
3   1       1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a single line dataframe and then use DataFrame.append():

```
df_to_append = pd.DataFrame([0, 0], columns=['column1', 'column2'])
your_df.append(df_to_append)
```

Checkout https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-append/
For more information provide your piece of code