# Join Dataframe with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df as

| Code | Designation |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Example 1 |
| 2F | Example 3 |
| 40 | Example 10 |

And I have dictionary as

```
matching = {
    'ABCD': ['01','60' ,'YZ'],
    'EFG': ['04','2F'],
    '007' : ['03','AB' ,'CD', 'DD'],
    ...
    }
```

I would like to add column on my df base on the matching dictionary as

| Code | Designation | Custom 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Example 1 | ABCD |
| 2F | Example 3 | EFG |
| 40 | Example 10 | null |

The lists contain unique value in whole dictionary
The matching can return 0 or 1 value

How should I proceed ?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366036/pandas-concat-dictionary-to-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @wjandrea has indicated I would flip the matching dictionary, but if that isn't possible here is a way to accomplish the task leaving matching as it is

```
import numpy as np
def searchDict(val, dct):
    for ky in dct.keys():
        if val in dct[ky]:
            return ky
    return np.nan  

df['New_col'] = [searchDict(x, matching) for x in df.index]
```

Answer (score 2):

Flip `matching` then map it over `Code`.

```
_matching_lookup = {e: k for k, v in matching.items() for e in v}
df['Custom 1'] = df['Code'].map(_matching_lookup)
df
```

```
   Code  Designation  Custom 1
0    01    Example 1      ABCD
1    2F    Example 3       EFG
2    40   Example 10       NaN
```